# Saving text into arrays C# forms

Tags: c#, forms, visual-studio

So I'm trying to create a username and password system in C# forms, I have a second form for creating your account, where you can enter what you want your Username and corresponding Password to be. I have 2 separate arrays, one for usernames one for passwords, and I want whatever the user types into the textbox for Username and Password to be held in their respective arrays, so I can associate them with one another. How would I go about saving what is written in the textbox, to an array?

Comment: Can you add a text to an array? Can you read a value from a textbox? Try small steps and if you are stuck, then you can ask a specific question.

Comment: Instead of two arrays that you need to keep in sync, create an Account class with username and password properties. And maybe use a extensible List instead of a fixed length Array

Answer (score 1):

Instead of Arrays you can use
C# - Hashtable

C# includes Hashtable collection in System.Collections namespace, which is similar to generic Dictionary collection. The Hashtable collection stores key-value pairs. It optimizes lookups by computing the hash code of each key and stores it in a different bucket internally and then matches the hash code of the specified key at the time of accessing values. 
Here is an example that demonstrates your idea

```
using System;
using System.Collections;
using System.Collections.Generic;

Hashtable ht = new Hashtable();

protected void btnLogin_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    ht.Add(txtUserName.Text, txtPassword.Text);    
}
```

Access Hashtable:

You can retrive the value of an existing key from the Hashtable using indexer. Please note that the hashtable indexer requires a key.

```
Hashtable ht = new Hashtable();

ht.Add(1, "One");
ht.Add(2, "Two");
ht.Add(3, "Three");
ht.Add(4, "Four");
ht.Add("Fv", "Five");
ht.Add(8.5F, 8.5F);

string strValue1 = (string)ht[2];
string strValue2 = (string)ht["Fv"];
float fValue = (float) ht[8.5F];

Console.WriteLine(strValue1);
Console.WriteLine(strValue2);
Console.WriteLine(fValue);
```

Output:

```
Two
Five
8.5
```

Comment: Why HashTable and not Dictionary?

Comment: Sure @JoelCoehoorn , you can go with Dictionary either, I just answered whats came to my mind.

Answer (score 0):

In `C#` arrays are best utilized when the number of items is known, and fixed. Otherwise a general `List<T>` would suffice to add/remove items.

I think what you are asking is how to develop a data model for registered users, and how to interact with this model using the UI.

There are several pieces to this puzzle:

### 1. Data Model

Start with a class to hold user information (`LoginUser` below) and a class to hold a list of authorized users (`UserRegistry` below).

[image: data]

Add methods to load/save the user registry in Xml or whatever storage you desire. In my example below I am using the builtin XmlSerializer to go from data to file and back.

The full code in my example is

```
/// <summary>
/// The user registry.
/// </summary>
[Serializable()]
[XmlType(AnonymousType = true)]
[XmlRoot(ElementName = "Users", Namespace = "", IsNullable = false)]
public partial class UserRegistry
{

    public UserRegistry()
    {
        this.Users= new List<LoginUser>();
    }

    /// <summary>
    /// The list of users
    /// </summary>
    [XmlElement("User")]
    public List<LoginUser> Users { get; set; }

    /// <summary>
    /// Find the user in the list that matches the userId
    /// </summary>
    public LoginUser this[string userId]
    {
        get
        {
            return Users.FirstOrDefault((item) => item.UserId.ToLowerInvariant().Equals(userId.ToLowerInvariant()));
        }
    }

    public void Add(LoginUser user)
    {
        this.Users.Add(user);
    }
    /// <summary>
    /// Load a user list from an xml string.
    /// </summary>
    public static UserRegistry FromXml(string xml)
    {
        var fs = new StringReader(xml);
        var xs = new XmlSerializer(typeof(UserRegistry));
        var list = xs.Deserialize(fs) as UserRegistry;
        fs.Close();
        return list;
    }

    /// <summary>
    /// Save a user list to an xml string.
    /// </summary>
    public string SaveToXml()
    {
        var fs = new StringWriter();
        var xs = new XmlSerializer(typeof(UserRegistry));
        xs.Serialize(fs, this);
        fs.Close();
        return fs.ToString();
    }
}

/// <summary>
/// A user entry
/// </summary>
[Serializable()]
[XmlType(AnonymousType = true)]
public partial class LoginUser
{
    public static readonly LoginUser Empty = new LoginUser()
    {
        UserId=string.Empty,
        Salt  = string.Empty,
        PasswordHash = string.Empty
    };
    /// <summary>
    /// The list of users
    /// </summary>
    [XmlAttribute("id")]
    public string UserId
    {
        get;
        set;
    }

    /// <summary>
    /// The salted hash of the password
    /// </summary>
    [XmlAttribute("pwd")]
    public string PasswordHash
    {
        get;
        set;
    }
    /// <summary>
    /// The salt value used in the hash.
    /// </summary>
    [XmlAttribute("salt")]
    public string Salt
    {
        get;
        set;
    }
}
```

and a sample corresponding XML file

```
// File: "UserList.xml"
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8" ?>
<Users>
  <User id="sue@email.com" pwd="Ei9p5Kiy8h7cy0nAxNimukxRhH4=" salt="OrAx1kBufa8=" />
  <User id="john@email.com" pwd="teeHjCrXzCxWosgZVTMWWeIvaso=" salt="hxQPkMK8t+0=" />
</Users>
```

Note that both registered users above share the same password, and by using a random "salt" to it, the password hash differs. The above implementation isn't the most secure, but it is a basic step above storing passwords as text. The password I used to generate both hashes above is the string `"12345678"`.

### 2. Login Form

The basic login form contains text boxes for the username and password

[image: login]

it also checks the password length before enabling the <kbd>OK</kbd> button. This button contains the code that builds a `LoginUser` from the UI.

The form has two properties, `LoginUser` for the current user and `UserRegistry` for the list of registered users. The list is populated when the form loads from the XML file. The current user is empty initially. I am enabling autocomplete on the username textbox for convenience, using the list of registered users.

```
public partial class LoginForm1 : Form
{
    public LoginUser User { get; set; }
    public UserRegistry UserRegistry { get; private set; }

    protected override void OnLoad(EventArgs e)
    {
        base.OnLoad(e);

        this.UserRegistry = UserRegistry.FromXml(File.ReadAllText("UserList.xml"));
        var usernames = UserRegistry.Users.Select((item) => item.UserId).ToArray();
        userNameTextBox.AutoCompleteSource = AutoCompleteSource.CustomSource;
        userNameTextBox.AutoCompleteCustomSource.AddRange(usernames);
        this.User = LoginUser.Empty;
    }

    // other code omitted
}
```

The main part of the code is checking for the password and registering a new user. I have two methods for these, `IsUserValid()` and `RegisterUser()` that are called from the <kbd>OK</kbd> button handler.

```
    public static bool IsUserValid(LoginUser user, string password)
    {
        var salt = Convert.FromBase64String(user.Salt);
        var pwd = Encoding.UTF7.GetBytes(password);
        var buffer = new byte[pwd.Length + salt.Length];
        Array.Copy(pwd, 0, buffer, 0, pwd.Length);
        Array.Copy(salt, 0, buffer, pwd.Length, salt.Length);
        var hash = sha1.ComputeHash(buffer);
        if (user.PasswordHash.Equals(Convert.ToBase64String(hash)))
        {
            return true;
        }
        return false;
    }

    public static LoginUser RegisterUser(string userName, string password)
    {
        var salt = new byte[8];
        rng.GetBytes(salt);
        var pwd = Encoding.UTF7.GetBytes(password);
        var buffer = new byte[pwd.Length + salt.Length];
        Array.Copy(pwd, 0, buffer, 0, pwd.Length);
        Array.Copy(salt, 0, buffer, pwd.Length, salt.Length);
        var hash = sha1.ComputeHash(buffer);
        return new LoginUser()
        {
            UserId = userName,
            Salt = Convert.ToBase64String(salt),
            PasswordHash = Convert.ToBase64String(hash)
        };
    }

    private void okButton_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        this.User = UserRegistry[userNameTextBox.Text];
        if (this.User!=null)
        {
            if (IsUserValid(User, passwordTextBox.Text))
            {
                this.DialogResult = DialogResult.OK;
                this.Close();
            }
            else
            {
                passwordTextBox.Clear();
                MessageBox.Show($"Incorrect password. Try Again.", "Login");
            }
        }
        else
        {
            if (MessageBox.Show($"User {userNameTextBox.Text} Not Found. Do you want to register?",
                "Login", MessageBoxButtons.YesNo)==DialogResult.Yes)
            {
                this.User = RegisterUser(userNameTextBox.Text, passwordTextBox.Text);
                this.UserRegistry.Add(User);
                MessageBox.Show($"User {userNameTextBox.Text} Registered.", "Login");
                this.DialogResult = DialogResult.OK;
                File.WriteAllText("UserList.xml", UserRegistry.SaveToXml());
                this.Close();
            }
        }            
    }
```

### 3. Validation

The main form must call the login form and if the user is valid, it will return a valid entry into the `User` property and return `DialogResult.OK` from the form `.ShowDialog()` method.

```
public partial class MDIParent1 : Form
{
    public MDIParent1()
    {
        InitializeComponent();
    }
    protected override void OnLoad(EventArgs e)
    {
        base.OnLoad(e);

        LoginForm1 login = new LoginForm1();
        login.StartPosition = FormStartPosition.CenterScreen;
        if (login.ShowDialog()==DialogResult.OK)
        {
            // Valid user
            userNameToolStripLabel.Text = login.User.UserId;
            return;
        }
        this.Close();
    }
}
```

In my example, I am using the identity of the user on the bottom right of the main form.

[image: mdi]